# With a standard key-matrix, how many IO pins are required for N keys?

Tags: circuit-design

Using a standard key-matrix such as this:

[image: key-matrix]

What formula stipulates the number of IO pins required for n number of keys?

Comment: Go on! How many do you think?

Comment: Instinctively I want to say sqrt(n) but that doesn't work... I've seen 26 IO pins for 109 Keys so 2/3 doesn't work either...

Comment: If you are allowed to use analog inputs, it might be possible to configure the key matrix with resistors as a DAC. A 4x4 matrix should provide an 8 bit analog value, and a single ADC pin would work, using 8 resistors.

Comment: @PStechPaul - I think I know what you mean, have you got an example circuit I could look at though? I've got a 12 bit ADC and ideally I need about 120 discrete keys with rollover... Not sure if that would work here?

Comment: That would be an 8x7 matrix so it might work with 15 resistor values based on powers of two. You should be able to put values in a spreadsheet and calculate the results to make sure there is no overlap and enough difference between values for the ADC to properly decode all keys. It might work best to use a constant current source that allows total resistance to be read.

Comment: Reverse-bias of switch diodes is ONE way to isolate rows and columns, but with analog techniques, it could be  possible to add a third dimension to an array.   Sixteen wires allows up to 64 keys with an 8x8 array, or 5x5x6 = 150 keys with a third dimension added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

m + n seems to work (obviously)

2x2 => 4

3x3 => 6

4x4 => 8

For a rectangular array,

2x3 => 6

4x3 => 7

1x8 => 9

Actually, for a general case, and minimum, ceil( 2 * sqrt(n) )

8 => 5.6 => 6 (2x4)

10 => 6.3 => 7 (5x2)

12 => 6.9 => 7 (4x3)

20 => 8.9 => 9 (4x5)

You could use just one analog 10 bit ADC pin and seven resistors for a 3x4 keypad. This simulation uses 16k, 8k, and 4k resistors for the 3 columns to 5 VDC, and 4k, 2k, 1k, and 500 ohm resistors feeding a 4k sampling resistor to the ADC pin. The 10 bit ADC values range from 171 to 488 counts:

[image: 3x4 Analog keypad]

Answer (score 2):

The required array for \$N\$ keys is some \$n \times m\$ array where \$nm \ge N\$.  If you want to minimize the number of pins for a given number of keys and \$N\$ isn't a perfect square, you'll need to mess around a bit with \$n\$ and \$m\$ to find the right number (but it's not far off of \$n = m = \left \lceil \sqrt N \right \rceil\$).

Note that there's a lot of good reasons to not stick to this.  Particularly for older processors supported by external circuitry, it would have been convenient to have 8 (or, less likely, 16) input lines, with as many driving lines as necessary to make up the difference.

Also, that sort of keyboard needs to be actively scanned.  You may wish to have some buttons connected directly to an interrupt, for example, or you may wish to bias the scheme toward more input lines and fewer scan lines, to speed things up.

Answer (score 1):

> Instinctively I want to say sqrt(n) but that doesn't work... I've seen 26 IO pins for 109 Keys so 2/3 doesn't work either...

You're on the right track if you're looking for the *minimum* number of I/O.

A simple example shows that it can be a little more complicated than that. A matrix of 20 elements, for example, would have 25 as the smallest perfect square that would accommodate it and require 5 + 5 = 10 I/O but it's clear that a 4 × 5 matrix would suffice and save one I/O.

In the case of the 109 key matrix the next perfect square is 144 suggesting that 12 + 12 = 24 I/O would suffice. There may be reasons for doing some other pattern such as 16 * 7 = 112 for 16 + 7 = 23 I/O. Reasons for this may include addition of LEDs as part of the matrix, PCB layout, an existing 16-bit bus or some requirements for shift / ctrl / alt key combinations.

Comment: So, find the next perfect square, square-root that, and then double it?

Comment: That's guaranteed to give you adequate I/O but not the minimum. As demonstrated by my 20-key example you can do better than that. Hmm - how to solve this by an algorithm other than trying all combinations?

Comment: @PStechPaul has it figured out rather neatly.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you arrange the matrix, which you don't say. Sometimes you have limitations how the matrix is easiest to arrange, or how far the matrix is from the MCU, or how quickly you want to scan the matrix, or if you want to use logic chips to help reduce pin count.

For 100 keys, you could use 10x10 matrix or 20 pins. But you can also arrange them into a 50x2 matrix which is 52 pins. For 120 keys, 11x11, or 60x2.

Depending on how the MCU ports are arranged, it might be simplest to arrange the matrix into 15x8 rather than 11x11 if your MCU has 8-bit IO ports, or if it suits better for the matrix, like computer keyboards can have 6 rows and 20 columns.

Assuming you arrange the matrix into a 15x8, and use 3-to-8 decoder chip, you only need 18 pins on the MCU. Or arrange it as 8x16 and use only 12 pins with the help of 2 decoder chips.

Of course if you use two 16-bit IO expanders over a bus like I2C, you can scan 256 keys, which requires 32 pins for matrix scanning, but the expanders only take 2 MCU pins.